# google chrome extension : how to get data from webpage and save it on user harddrive permanently?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have this website which I frequently visit to lookup a German language word meanings in English. I want to save the text from each webpage I visit of the site in a json file by highlighting it. How do I go about doing this? Which api of google chrome extension should I refer to?

Also will a firefox addon be faster to learn and develop? I have some programming exp in html, JS and CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to store data between browser restarts then take a look at [LocalStorage API](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/). If you actually need to create a file there is a [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but it has its limitations and not very easy to use.

Chrome extensions are much easier to learn and create than Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pure HTML5 web storage.

**Its already been answered here:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194784/which-browsers-support-html5-offline-storage

**- or take a look for more reference in most HTML5 tutorials:**

- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html
- http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/
- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp